# I had some code in php and in header of that code i want to give link of my ionic app page

Tags: php, html, ionic-framework

`page.php`:

```
if($order_status != 'Success'){ 
    $date = date('d-M-Y h:i:sa');
    $new = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `event_reg` SET payment_date = '$date', status_text = '$order_status;', tid = '$transaction_id', order_id = '$order_id' WHERE reg_id = '$tidd'");

    header("location:canceled.php?reg_id=$tidd");
}
```

In header location of page is `canceled.php` but I don't want this. I want to redirect it in my ionic app page how it can possible. My php page is on server and project is on `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
header("location:canceled.php?reg_id=$tidd");
```

use

```
header("Location: https://YourIonicAppUrl/");
```

Comment: my app is on localserver